# Bootstrap Modals misbehaving

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to add a BootStrap modal to an already-existing page and I'm running into the following problem:

The modal displays exactly as I would expect it to, content in place looking quite beautiful but I have two problems. If I specify only `class="modal"` the modal displays by default when the page loads and will not close. If I include `class="modal hide"` then the modal does not display at page load but also doesn't close when the appropriate buttons are clicked.

I'm not making any big departures from the [modals sample code](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) on the Bootstrap site, any ideas what's going wrong?

Here's the button that's supposed to launch the modal:

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#testmodal" >About</a>
```

And here's the modal itself:

```
    <div class="modal hide fade in" id="testmodal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
            <h3>Modal Header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>body</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And for the record, yes I did remember to include bootstrap-modal.js and bootstrap-transition.js

Comment: Are you sure jquery and bootstrap get loaded correctly? Open up a console (firebug or the chrome console) and make sure you don't get any errors.

Comment: @geoffreydv you should make that an answer so I can accept it. Despite the fact that I explicitly selected those modules on Bootstrap's download page for some reason they were not actually in the zip. I had to go download everything from GitHub and manually place files - not sure why that happened... In any case that was the issue, thanks!~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad your problem is resolved.

Also if you want the default bootstrap functionality without customizing anything just use the big download button on the main page. This zip file contains a default bootstrap.min.js file that includes all the plugins (like the modal dialogs etc). If you use that one instead of all the seperate javascript files your page has to make less requests and load faster.

Answer (score 0):

your close link should be like this:

```
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
```

since, data-dismiss is a custom HTML5 data attribute. Here it is used to close the modal window.